Is it necessary to use Nuxt Server as an intermediary between my external Django API and the Nuxt 3 frontend in SSR mode?
I am developing a SaaS application using a backend architecture with a Django REST API and a PostgreSQL database, while the frontend uses Nuxt 3 with TypeScript, Tailwind, and TanStack Query for API request management. I have enabled Server-Side Rendering (SSR) by setting ssr: true in the nuxt.config.ts file :
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,
})

In my current architecture, I have a server/api/ directory within my Nuxt 3 application containing multiple files that represent endpoints to interact with the Django API. For instance, I have a file server/api/projects/index.ts that points to the Django endpoint /api/projects/ to fetch all projects.
Nuxt Server Integration:
Nuxt Server Directory Structure:
server/api/projects/index.ts : Points to the Django endpoint /api/projects/ to fetch all projects.
server/api/projects/[id].get.ts : Fetches a project by its ID from /api/projects/detail/${projectId}/.
API Interaction Logic:
These endpoints are used within a service handler (api/projects.api.ts) that provides functions like getAllProjects, getProjectById, and deleteProjectById.
Composable (useProjects.ts):
The composable useProjects.ts uses the functions in api/projects.api.ts to manage project data and interact with the Nuxt Server endpoints in server/api/projects/. It leverages useQuery from TanStack Query for efficient state management.
Question :
Is it necessary to have an intermediary Nuxt server between the Nuxt 3 frontend and an external Django API? Does this provide any specific benefits for Server-Side Rendering (SSR), or can the Nuxt 3 frontend directly interact with the Django API while maintaining SSR features?
Thank you for your help!
Application Structure :
frontend/
├─ api/                         # Functions to call the API server Nuxt 3 (server/api/)
│  └─ projects.api.ts
├─ app.vue
├─ assets/
│  └─ css/
│     └─ tailwind.css
├─ composables/                 # Composables to call functions in api/projects.api.ts
│  └─ useProjects.ts            # and share data between components
├─ nuxt.config.ts
├─ pages
│  ├─ ecowall/
│  │  ├─ conception
│  │  │  └─ [projectId]
│  │  │     └─ paroi
│  │  │        ├─ [paroiId].vue
│  │  │        └─ new-paroi.vue
│  │  ├─ index.vue
│  │  └─ projects
│  │     ├─ [projectId].vue
│  │     └─ index.vue           # I use my composables useProjects.ts here to get all projects
│  └─ index.vue
├─ plugins
│  └─ vue-query.ts
├─ server/                     # Intermediary server to call the Django API endpoints
│  ├─ api/
│  │  ├─ projects/
│  │  │  ├─ [id].delete.ts
│  │  │  ├─ [id].get.ts
│  │  │  ├─ create.post.ts
│  │  │  └─ index.ts
│  └─ tsconfig.json
└─ tsconfig.json

I have implemented an intermediary Nuxt server to act as a bridge between the Nuxt 3 frontend and the external Django API. My expectation was that this intermediary layer would improve performance, ensure security, and enhance Server-Side Rendering (SSR). However, I'm uncertain if this approach is necessary.
What I tried:

I created several API endpoints in the server/api directory of my Nuxt 3 application that directly point to the Django API endpoints:

server/api/projects/index.ts points to /api/projects/.
server/api/projects/[id].get.ts points to /api/projects/detail/${projectId}/.

I created a service handler (api/projects.api.ts) that provides functions to interact with these Nuxt server endpoints.

I used a composable (useProjects.ts) to manage project data and interact with the Nuxt server endpoints via TanStack Query.


What I expected:
Improved performance due to better caching and SSR benefits.
Enhanced security since the Nuxt server acts as an intermediary between the frontend and the Django API.
What actually happened:
The setup works fine, but it adds complexity to the architecture.
I'm not sure if this intermediary Nuxt server is necessary or if the Nuxt 3 frontend can directly interact with the external Django API while maintaining SSR features.
Therefore, I would like to confirm whether this approach provides any specific benefits for SSR or if a direct connection between the frontend and the Django API is sufficient.

You could have some performance benefits of fetching the data on the server and pushing it to the client-side rather than fetching it there (removes JSON overhead) and a few things like that, so kinda improve the performance.
Also, if you use the full-static mode of Nuxt (also available with Nuxt3), then you could skip any external calls and have it set at build-time.
So, kinda helps with SSR depending on what you do within your app.
Might bring some benefit or not at all.
Enhance security? Quite the opposite. Between the hydration process and the fact that you're working with an isomorphic app in Nuxt, it might lead to more leaks than if you keep Django and Nuxt separate.
You could overall use Nuxt's server directory for a few endpoints if the benefit is obvious but otherwise, no real benefit besides debugging complexity as you guessed right.
If you do some heavy typing on Nuxt's server side, maybe you could see a point. Also, you might have a faster response asking Nuxt's endpoint rather than yours because you will skip a real network trip (just do it locally) but you also need to have the data available in your Nuxt app, so not that easy either.

TLDR: keep them separate and use Nuxt's server directory in specific cases with obvious benefits.
